# given IProject object programmatically find if it is shared with a repository

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a the IProject object, of a project created in eclipse. I want to find if this project is linked to any repository or not. I need to do this programatically. Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.eclipse.team.core.RepositoryProvider` has a `getProvider(IProject)` static method to get the repository information for a project.